# A good way to detect alpha channel in a video using ffmpeg/ffprobe

Tags: video, ffmpeg, alpha, ffprobe, transcoding

In my Django application, uploaded video files are transcoded into some particular format using ffmpeg.

I now need a way to reliably detect whether uploaded videos have alpha channel or not. I normally use ffprobe for getting video metadata. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: **Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/**. Please delete this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in two steps, using ffprobe.

#1

```
ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=pix_fmt -of compact=p=0:nk=1 "$FILE"
```

This will print the pixel format of the video stream. All pixel formats with alpha component have `a` in their name but not all formats with `a` have alpha. So, run..

#2

```
ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries pixel_format=name:flags=alpha -of compact=p=0  | grep "$PIX_FMT|" | grep -oP "(?<=alpha=)\d"
```

where $PIX_FMT is the readout printed in step 1. The result will be `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. Turn off the banner, and set the `-loglevel` to error only, and pipe the results to grep for `"pix_fmt"`:

```bash
ffprobe -hide_banner -loglevel error -show_entries \
   stream "input.png" | grep "pix_fmt"
```

Returns `pix_fmt=rgba`

For a JPEG, or other file missing the alpha transparency channel, expect an output of: `pix_fmt=yuvj444p`